# Vspace in Outlook 2007/2010

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I have an html newsletter which works in most email carriers but the formatting is messed up in outlook. I have put vspace="10" on the image tag to put 10px margin on the top and bottom of the image to have a space between the image and text below it. However, in Outlook the vspace is not being picked up and the text appears directly under the image with no space between.

Does anyone know how to get this to work? I tried to put a margin-bottom of 10px on the image, but again this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to use a nested table and define the height of the row to be 10px. What you are contending with in Outlook 2007+ is Word HTML rendering which handles CSS in it's own special way.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML Email there is a lot of nuances between the different browsers. One thing i have learnt from creating emails is that it needs to be extremely simple. Both margin & padding are not supported by Outlook (due to it using the word rendering engine).

**The solution**

Replace the image and the space with a table containing 2 spacer gifs and the image in the centre. For example (you need to use absolute paths to your images):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img style="display:block" border="0" src="images/spacer.gif" width="IMAGEWIDTH" height="10" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img style="display:block" border="0" src="YOUR IMAGE" width="" height="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img style="display:block" border="0" src="images/spacer.gif" width="IMAGEWIDTH" height="10" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```